# newFixedThreadPool creates more tasks than needed

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, future

I have method which creates N threads (for example 50 threads). These created threads create new threads with `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20)`.
So `50 * 20 = 1000` or a bit more maybe created threads while application is running.
But in real situation the number of threads may be more than 10000 and more! How to fix this? What am I doing wrong?

Here is a part of code which create threads and add them to Future list:

        `while(taskCount != 0 || futureSize > 0)
        {
            if(taskCount > 0)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < taskCount; i++)
                {
                    if(i % 100 == 0)
                    {
                        checkAlive(taskId);`

```
                    date = new Date();

                    System.gc();
                }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                future.add(exec.submit(new Task());

                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Maybe this happened because of using Future? Or why? Why number of threads is out of control? Because of that I have out-of-memory exceptions and threads number seems to be unlimited. And if threads are waiting in the pool why so much memory is allocates for this each threads as I know waiting threads in the pool don't use so much memory.

Here are screens before and after:
[image: before]
[image: after]

Comment: I don't see any call to `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20)`. That method would be interesting.

Comment: You forgot to include the thread creation in your code sample.

Comment: @toto2 it's `future.add(exec.submit(new Task());` in the sample

Comment: @user802421 sure, here it is: http://pastebin.com/Ny21x2EX and thCount is equal to 20. This code is above the loop in the sample.

Comment: I meant like user802421.  And your pastebin link still doesn't show how and when you create the thread pools.

Comment: @toto2 what do you mean? This? http://pastebin.com/Dv5kqZPA

Comment: I don't see anything wrong so far, so maybe the problem is with the 50 initial threads.  Also it could be that `new Task()` creates more threads.

Comment: @toto2 no, `new Task()` do some simple fast job and return result (true if all done or false if some exception happened). I've found a bit information about my problem and maybe it would be someone helpful: http://www.coderanch.com/t/510311/threads/java/FixedThreadPool-Blocking-submit

Comment: I don't what software you got the load images from, but it's possible that it has some different definition for a "thread".  You can try [visualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/monitor_tab.html) to see how many threads there are.  Also, in Netbeans and Eclipse, you can see the threads live in debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

You should not create new `ThreadPool`s inside your threads, you should create the thread pool first and then add your new threads to the thread pool.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357985/best-practice-for-thread-arrays-java/8358133#8358133) for an example.

```
// Thread pool for the collectors.
ExecutorService threads = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_THREADS);
// Futures of all collectors running in the pool.
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Future> collectors = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Future>();
...
// Make my Callable.
Callable<Void> c = new FileListCollector(path, recurse, filter);
// Start it up and keep track of it so we can find out when it has finished.
collectors.add(threads.submit(c));
```

Comment: Yep I know but I have threads which I add to thread pool and which should create another threads (which do something else).